# Calling a method with getattr in Python

Tags: python, metaclass, getattr

How to call a method using getattr?
I want to create a metaclass, which can call non-existing methods of some other class that start with the word 'oposite_'. The method should have the same number of arguments, but to return the opposite result.

```
def oposite(func):
    return lambda s, *args, **kw:  not oposite(s, *args, **kw)


class Negate(type):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('oposite_'):
            return oposite(self.__getattr__(name[8:]))        
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.__getattr__ = Negate.__getattr__


class P(metaclass=Negate):
    def yep(self):
        return True
    def maybe(self, sth):
        return sth
```

But the problem is that

```
self.__getattr__(sth)
```

returns a NoneType object.

```
>>> p = P()
>>> p.oposite_yep()    #should be False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#115>", line 1, in <module>
    p.oposite_yep()
TypeError: <lambda>() takes at least 1 positional argument (0 given)
>>> p.oposite_maybe(False)    #should be true
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: For the record, "oposite" is spelled with two p's. But, as a colleague of mine used to say, "Programmers don't need to spell correctly, they need to spell consistently."

Answer (score 2):

```
class Negate(type):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('oposite_'):
            def oposite(*args,**kwargs):
                return not getattr(self,name[8:])(*args,**kwargs)
            return oposite
        else:
            raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
                                 (type(self).__name__, name))

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.__getattr__ = Negate.__getattr__

class P(metaclass=Negate):
    def yep(self):
        return True
    def same(self,x,y):
        return x==y

p=P()
print(p.oposite_yep())
# False
print(p.oposite_same(1,2))
# True
print(p.nope())
```

By the way, you can also do this with a class decorator instead of a metaclass:

```
def Negater(cls):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('oposite_'):
            def oposite(*args,**kwargs):
                return not getattr(self,name[8:])(*args,**kwargs)
            return oposite
        else:
            raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
                                 (type(self).__name__, name))
    setattr(cls,'__getattr__',__getattr__)
    return cls

@Negater
class P():
    ....
```

Comment: ok, but that is if yep has no args except of self. If yep takes another argument, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to handle the case where the attribute name *doesn't* start with `'oposite_'`.

Comment: It's just one return statement more. But even with it, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `"TypeError: <lambda>() takes at least 1 positional argument (0 given)
"`

This has nothing to do with you metaclass magic, it's because you don't pass any argument to the `lambda` function.

When you do this:

```
p.oposite_yep
```

It call `__getattr__`, which returns the result of `opposite()`, which is a `lambda` function.

Your lamda function is returned, it is created on the fly, and never bouned to the instance. It won't receive 'self' as a first argument: it's just an anonymous function returned on the fly.

So when you do this:

```
p.oposite_yep()
```

You basically call the lambda, without any argument, which cause the error.